# Windows Form - ListView - Removing lines between columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, user-interface

I need to display a `ListView` in WinForms which should not have any lines between columns. I tried `GridLines=false` and also tried setting `HeaderStyle` to `ColumnHeaderStyle.None`. But this is not working. I want to remove the 2 vertical lines coming in the middle.

[screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4bcee1f639.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4bcee1f639.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the view into Details

and GridLines=false

like:

```
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.listView1.GridLines = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

`GridLine = False` should work. (See Pramodh answer.) If not, you have something else wrong. If you setting this property in code, make sure the control's handle has been created. The method `CreateControl` and `IsHandleCreated` are helpful.

A common problem in C# that affects controls is accessing control properties in the form's constructor. Usually, the control handles are not created until they are "visible", which doesn't happen until the form is loaded. Therefore, if setting these properties in the form constructor, move the code to the `Load` event which is recommended by Microsoft.

**Control.CreateControl Method**

> The CreateControl method forces a
>   handle to be created for the control
>   and its child controls. This method is
>   used when you need a handle
>   immediately for manipulation of the
>   control or its children; simply
>   calling a control's constructor does
>   not create the Handle.
>
> CreateControl does not create a
>   control handle if the control's
>   Visible property is false. You can
>   either call the CreateHandle method or
>   access the Handle property to create
>   the control's handle regardless of the
>   control's visibility, but in this
>   case, no window handles are created
>   for the control's children.